# Make fields readonly in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am making a form where user can add more fields by clicking on add more button. for that I am using ng-repeat and when user click on add more button one field is pushed to array in ng-repeat results into one more field.

Now for some cases ng-repeat array may include some fields , I want to make them readonly but if user click on add more button then that field can be editable.
My code :

**HTML code**

```
 <div ng-repeat="field in ui_fields">
     <label for="Language">Field Name :</label><input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="field.name">
     <label for="Language">Field type :</label>
     <select class="form-control" ng-model="field.type">
         <option value="">Select field type</option>
         <option value="timedate">Date & Time</option>
         <option value="text">Text</option>
     </select>
 </div>
```

**Angular code**

```
$scope.add_extra_field = function(){
    $scope.ui_fields.push({ 
        name: "",
        type: ""
      });
    }
```

Comment: What is the rule of being editable? Always the last element is editbale until a new one is added?

Comment: @hansmaad No new one is added by click add more button then that can be editable , readonly will be applicable to those if they are already exists in array

Comment: Which action makes a new element an existing one? click adds a new item I can edit, and than? What makes this item readonly?

Comment: @hansmaad I am using Python as backend so when I am sending fields from backend then those fields must be readonly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use an extra field `isreadonly` in `ui_fields` array and the [ngReadOnly](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngReadonly) directive, like :

Your HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="field in ui_fields">
    <label for="Language">Field Name :</label><input class="form-control" ng-readonly="field.isreadonly" type="text" ng-model="field.name">
    <label for="Language">Field type :</label>
    <select class="form-control"  ng-disabled="field.isreadonly" ng-model="field.type">
        <option value="">Select field type</option>
        <option value="timedate">Date & Time</option>
        <option value="text">Text</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Your javascript:

```
$scope.add_extra_field = function(){
    $scope.ui_fields.push({ 
        name: "",
        type: "",
        isreadonly: false
      });
    }
```

Comment: It is working fine thx, But it will be  `ng-disabled` instead of  `ng-readonly` in case of select type .

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about your exact use case, but you can use [`ngReadonly`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngReadonly) to make controls conditionally read only. In this example I made the last row readonly:

http://plnkr.co/edit/sZhKsjWoFBh30ikKZeN8?p=preview

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" 
       ng-model="field.name" ng-readonly="$index < ui_fields.length - 1" />
```

**Edit:**
I forked to match your actual use case http://plnkr.co/edit/DT7oMAhkjGxGa1GRN5uP?p=preview

In the save function you use to send the edited data to the server you can set the index of last saved data. Use this index as condition for `ngReadonly`

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" 
       ng-model="field.name" ng-readonly="$index <= savedIndex" />
```

Controller:

```
$scope.add_extra_field = function(){
  $scope.ui_fields.push({ 
      name: "",
      type: ""
    });
  }
$scope.save = function() {
   // send to server
   $scope.savedIndex = $scope.ui_fields.length -1;
}
```